# chromium core dumped - libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)

Tags: nvidia, chromium, crash

Until yesterday, I was using chromium just fine in my Ubuntu 20.10. I don't remember whether it started after I made an upgrade on apt-get, or after a snap refresh, but I clicked Chromium icon again and it would not start.

I tried from the terminal and I got:

```
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[13444:13444:0521/212248.340845:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(426)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is egl
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

`vainfo` output:

```
vainfo 
libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

My board:

```
nvidia-debugdump -l
Found 1 NVIDIA devices
    Device ID:              0
    Device name:            NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960   (*PrimaryCard)
    GPU internal ID:        GPU-c862d15e-8977-6806-71c5-c318b0268e1a
```

I am not 100% sure on how to debug and find the issue.

QUESTION:
What should I read to learn how to debug the above and find the error by myself?

Comment: `chromium` on 20.10 is a snap, and when I've had issues with chromium on more recent releases; I've always found solution at https://forum.snapcraft.io/

Comment: I tried reverting chromium and it didn't work... it really seems a problem with video hardware acceleration config...

Comment: What do you mean by reverting?   did you switch from *beta* or *edge* to *stable* or something else? as you're talking about a *snap*

Comment: I mean `snap revert chromium`

Comment: Fantastic - I did nothing, today I accidentally clicked chromium button and it's working now...

Comment: Haha! So will the solution be to accidentally click chromium and the is solved? :D

Comment: Right? LoL Maybe someone from the chromium team saw by ticket, solved it and didn't write it here because the fix was quicker than commenting it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often this behavior occurs in a virtual environment where the browser is launched

It doesn't matter snapcraft or apt repositories (chromium / chromium-browser)
the problem is not solved

**libva-*** packages **won't** help you

**I just disabled the gpu** chromium --disable-gpu in command line

Add this flag to the shortcut that launches your chromium